# Log transformation leading to extremely negative R-squared and extremle values for MSE

Tags: regression, python, data-transformation, logarithm, mean-absolute-deviation

I have a set of data and I am using this code on it:

```
categorical_columns = ["x3"]
numerical_columns = ["x1", "x2", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x8"]


preprocessor = make_column_transformer(
(OneHotEncoder(drop="first"), categorical_columns),
(StandardScaler(), numerical_columns),
    remainder="passthrough",
    verbose_feature_names_out=False,
)

model = make_pipeline(
preprocessor,
TransformedTargetRegressor(
regressor=LinearRegression(), **func=np.log10, inverse_func=sp.special.exp10**
),
)  # this is because y is positively skewed (1.2 of skewness) and can't have negative values
```

When I do this and run a linear regression, I get the following metrics:

- R-squared on training set: -1936.24
- R-squared on testing set: -2227.20
- MedAE on training set: 0.80
- MedAE on testing set: 0.81
- MSE on training set: 20747.23
- MSE on test set: 20747.23

If I remove the log transformation, I get the following metrics:

- R-squared on training set: 0.86
- R-squared on testing set: 0.84
- MedAE on training set: 0.54
- MedAE on testing set: 0.53
- MSE on training set: 1.53
- MSE on test set: 1.53

For reference this is the code:

```
model = make_pipeline(
preprocessor,
TransformedTargetRegressor(
regressor=LinearRegression()
),
)
```

The thing is then my linear regression starts predicting negative values when $y$ doesn't have a single negative value, yet it does have a lot of values very close to $0$. Using a standard scaler yields the same results has the no log transformation. What am I doing wrong ?

Information that may or may not be relevant - doing a ridge or a lasso regression gives the same results as a linear regression (so probably something is very wrong, right?)

---

MWE

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, median_absolute_error, r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor
import scipy as sp


X = data.drop(columns = "y")
y = data.y

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)

categorical_columns = ["x3"]
numerical_columns = ["x1", "x2", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x8"]

# Preprocessor
preprocessor = make_column_transformer(
    (OneHotEncoder(drop="first"), categorical_columns),
    (StandardScaler(), numerical_columns),
    remainder="passthrough",
    verbose_feature_names_out=False,
)

# Model with Log Transformation
model_log = make_pipeline(
    preprocessor,
    TransformedTargetRegressor(
        regressor=LinearRegression(), func=np.log10, inverse_func=sp.special.exp10
    ),
)

# Model without Log Transformation
model_no_log = make_pipeline(
    preprocessor,
    LinearRegression(),
)
# Train and evaluate models
for model, name in zip([model_log, model_no_log], ['With Log', 'Without Log']):
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    r2 = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
    medae = median_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred)
    mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
    print(f"{name}: R-squared: {r2:.2f}, MedAE: {medae:.2f}, MSE: {mse:.2f}")
```

data sample :

```
x1,   x2,   x3,x4,  x5,  x6,    x8,   y
67.55,64.07,4,3.71,0.027,0.019,0.022,3.99
30.51,29.74,3,1.47,0.004,0.018,-0.004,0.96
86.74,86.70,3,0.68,0.021,0.018,0.029,4.24
0.97,0.90,1,0.91,0.037,0.017,0.034,0.08
76.41,70.19,4,0.25,0.018,0.020,0.008,10.69
38.59,35.01,3,1.23,0.029,0.017,0.016,5.36
51.75,51.46,3,2.29,0.021,0.016,0.026,1.08
16.87,15.42,3,1.28,0.037,0.016,0.033,2.42
47.12,42.60,3,2.43,0.035,0.016,0.033,5.35
41.20,39.13,2,1.08,0.037,0.018,0.046,3.40
7.35,7.18,2,1.77,0.029,0.017,0.032,0.22
28.23,27.87,4,2.45,0.033,0.021,0.018,1.77
54.31,49.06,1,0.85,0.036,0.015,0.040,5.53
2.46,2.25,4,1.02,0.009,0.017,0.013,0.27
65.19,61.14,1,0.95,0.047,0.015,0.051,4.19
27.18,24.74,2,1.90,0.018,0.019,0.009,2.48
75.26,75.22,3,0.42,0.003,0.014,0.005,0.99
72.62,72.01,2,0.13,0.021,0.016,0.024,3.43
16.22,15.92,1,0.99,0.050,0.022,0.048,0.30
79.54,75.36,3,0.29,0.007,0.019,0.022,5.67
```

Comment: R squared can't be negative.  I don't know what you are doing wrong, but something is wrong in your code. 

However, questions about coding are off topic here, so I am voting to close.

Comment: So where do I ask ? I am sorry, I thought this was the place to ask such questions

Comment: @PeterFlom It depends on how you calculate $R^2$. There are multiple definitions that agree in simple settings but disagree as you move beyond them, and some of these calculations can give [tag:negative-r-squared].

Comment: @Dave OK, but not in a simple regression, at least as far as I know. Ant that seems to be the situation here.

Comment: @Coding_noob Well, it's not closed yet,  and others may not agree that it's off topic, but you could try a Python list of some sort (sorry, I don't use Python so I can't be specific).

Comment: I disagree with the close vote as "programming-related", I believe this is absolutely a statistical question ("why is my R-squared negative if I log-transform?"), which could absolutely be asked in Python, R or slide rule. That said, please edit your post to provide a *Minimal Reproducible Example* that still exhibits the problematic behavior. (It may well be that you find the solution in the process of cutting your example down to an MWE.)

Comment: Welcome to CV @Coding_noob. I made some considerable formatting changes to your post because it was pretty hard to read with all the random code formatting and bolding.  Be careful with over-stylizing the fonts. Sometimes it just serves as a distraction for potential answerers.

Comment: @PeterFlom I actually show an example with negative $R^2$ for simple regression [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/631110/should-i-remove-the-intercept-when-i-have-one-dummy-variable-that-covers-all-the/631112#631112), though it is meant to be an extreme case.

Comment: The problem seems to be with the data. If I create samples of the data for example with 10,100,1000,10000 entries the R Squared will keep going down and the MSE up with the logs, so some values were altering the calculation. So after a few tries I was able to find with a small sample where I reproduced the problem. I will post it

Comment: I withdrew my close vote.